# How to calculate area in a image

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

Edited:
The original image is attached as [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6EaE.jpg), I want to find the area of the hand which has the glittering on it. I have processed the image to find the glittering as attached in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKAcB.jpg).

Now, I need to find the black parts in the image. I am using OpenCV on Android Studio.

The code:

```
int[] allpixels = new int[bitmap_original.getHeight() * bitmap_original.getWidth()];
outputBitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, outputBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, outputBitmap.getWidth(), outputBitmap.getHeight());
double value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < allpixels.length; i++) {
    value++; 
    //minus the white in the image
    if (allpixels[i] == Color.WHITE) {
        value--;
    }
}
```

Images:[image: Output image]

[image: Original input image]

Comment: Did you really take a screenshot of an image instead of just using the original image? Also, if you count everything that isn't white as black, are you actually sure that the image is just black-white format and there are no pixels that are netiher white or black?

Comment: Just count the black pixels(0 value) in the image. What is difficult with this?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I think OP is interested in approximating the area, so they're probably looking for ways to fill in the "holes".

Comment: _"But it does not seem to perform an accurate calculation."_ How did you define what's the "accurate calculation"?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen, i have edited the question, please take a look. Thank you

Comment: @aa13579 Your new edit changes the problem and makes me think that this is an "xy problem". The problem is not how you compute the area: once you detect the glitter you lose all discriminatory information and it makes sense to just sum up the black pixels (as Yunus Temrulek pointed out initially). The problem is how you detect the glitter (*e.g.* on the thumb we can clearly see that the detection creates artifacts), improve that and you'll get a better approximation to the area.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Well your new edit changes the question entirely. In that case it seems that the inaccuracy of your results should be addressed by improving the way you detect your glitter, not the way you compute your area. Once the detection is improved you can just compute the area as Yunus Temurlenk suggests in his answer.

There are probably much more sophisticated methods, but a quick hack that might give slightly better results is to use [mathematical morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology), *e.g.* a succession of [openings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Opening) (disclaimer: I have absolutely no expertise in that field):

```
#Octave code
I=imread(your_image);

N=20;
se=strel("square",20);
J=I;
for i=1:N
    J=imopen(J,se);
end

imagesc(J);
```

[image]

Yes, it could be done much better, but even so, counting the non-zero pixels in this image will probably give you a better approximation of the area than counting them in the original one.

Comment: thanks. May I know what software you used to achieve this? i have updated the question, could you pls take a look?

Comment: @aa13579 As specified in the comment in the begining of the snippet, it's octave (an opensource matlab clone, more or less), but any decent image processing library should have similar implementations available.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has an OpenCV tag here are a few pointers in that direction:

1. Checkout the [OpenCV Android](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html) guide for setup (currently there's an HTTPS issue with the site: Advanced > Proceed should do the trick)
2. After you apply the morphological open filter (as Ash correctly advises) using [`dilate()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#dilate(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)) you can [`findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html) (external only, simplified is what you're after)
3. You can then easily get the first contour's area via [`contourArea
   ()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#contourArea(org.opencv.core.Mat)), the [`boundingRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#boundingRect(org.opencv.core.Mat)) (or [`minAreaRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#minAreaRect(org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f)) for the oriented bounding box) among many other metrics derrived from contours

If you simply need to count the number of pixels you can invert the image use [`countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#countNonZero(org.opencv.core.Mat))